# laplace equation with bisection boundary condition on upper side

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, boundary-value-problem, laplacian

> solve laplace equation  $ U_{xx} + U_{yy} = 0 $ with given boundary
> condition : $ (x,y) \in (0,a) \times (0,b) $ $\begin{cases} U_x(0,y)
> = U(x,0) = U_x(a,y) = 0 \\ U(x,b)=  c= constant \hspace{3mm}  ,0 < x < a_1 < a \\ U_y(x,b) = 0 \hspace{3mm}  ,a_1 < x < a \end{cases}$

**my approach:**
I decided to introduce a linking condition $U(a_1,y) = f(x)$ , therefore we will continue solving two parts separately and connect them at the end .

*first problem:*

$ U_{xx} + U_{yy} = 0  , \hspace{4mm} (x,y) \in (0,a_1) \times (0,b)$

boundary conditions: $\begin{cases} U_x(0,y)
= U(x,0) = 0\\U(a_1,y) = f(x) \\ U(x,b)=  c= constant \end{cases}$

*solution of first problem:*
$$U(x,y)=v(x,y)+w(x,y)$$
dirichlet BC $\implies w(x,y)=0+\frac{y}{b}\times c=\frac{yc}{b}$
$$\implies u(x,y)=\frac{yc}{b}+v(x,y)$$
$$\implies \begin{cases}U_x(0,y)=v_x(0,y)=0\\U(a_1,y)=\frac{yc}{b}+v(a_1,y) \implies v(a_1,y)=f(y)-\frac{yc}{b} \end{cases}$$

so all BCs are now homogenous except one side and we can solve problem for $v(x,y)$:

$$\implies v(x,y)=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\sin(\frac{n\pi}{b}y)\cosh(\frac{2n-1}{2b}\pi x)$$

$$\implies U(x,y)=  \frac{yc}{b}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\sin(\frac{n\pi}{b}y)\cosh(\frac{2n-1}{2b}\pi x)$$

$$U(a_1,y)=f(y)= \frac{yc}{b}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\sin(\frac{n\pi}{b}y)\cosh(\frac{2n-1}{2b}\pi a_1)$$
$A_n$ could be found using fourier series of $f(x)$, therefore the first problem is solved

*second problem:*

$ U_{xx} + U_{yy} = 0  , \hspace{4mm} (x,y) \in (a_1,a) \times (0,b)$

boundary conditions: $\begin{cases} 
U(x,0) = U_x(a,y) = U_y(x,b)=0\\U(a_1,y) = f(x) \end{cases}$

*solution of second problem:*
BCs are all homogenous except the introduced linking condition , if the rectangular was attached to y-axis I knew how to simply solve it but now I don't know what should be placed in $......$ below
$$ U(x,y)=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n\sin(\frac{2n-1}{2b}\pi y)\cosh(.......x)$$

I think it should be solved in this way but I'm not sure :

$$ U(x,y)=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n\sin(\frac{2n-1}{2b}\pi y)\cosh(\frac{2n-1}{2b}\pi(x-a))$$

and the other difficulty is if both above problems are solved how can I sum up them to achieve a single solution for the main problem ?

thanks for your help!